# HTML-How to submit a form with sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php, html, sweetalert

somebody knows how to submit a form in html with sweetalert?

I have this checkbox and I want that onchange "direct" me to the sweetalert js with 2 Buttons. One with "No" and one with "Yes". The "Yes" button should now be the new "onchange" and with the "No" button the submit should be canceled.

```
<form method='post' action='....'>    
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_admin" onchange="submit();" checked>
</form>
```

Hope you know what I mean. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would normally do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-click="swal-danger"]').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this).parents('form');
                swal({
                  title: "Are You Sure?",
                  text: "Are You Sure You Want To Delete.",
                  icon: "error",
                  buttons: true,
                  dangerMode: true,
                })
                    .then((willDelete) => {
                      if (willDelete) {                         
                        swal(form.submit(), {
                          icon: "success",
                        });
                      } else {
                        
                      }
            });
      });
});
```

Use this while submitting the form via swal/Sweetalert

```
swal(form.submit()
```

Then create a form submit button but without the type submit as bellow

```
<form method='post' action='....'>    
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-click="swal-danger">DELETE USER</button>
</form>
```

Make sure your button have this on your button `data-click="swal-danger"`

Comment: and how the html onchange should look?